# Negative elements in pivot column when solving LP Simplex method?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

what do I do if all the elements in the pivot column are negative? Details are as follow:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\max &-60000y_1 + 4800y_2 + 900y_3\\
\text{s.t.:}&\begin{cases}-50y_1 +6y_2 +y_3 \leq3\\-75y_1+ 6.75y_2 + y_3 \leq 1.8\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

The most negative elements in the bottom row is $-60000$ which defines pivot column as the first non-basic var vector $(-50, -75)$.
What do we do in this situation since pivot element is not allowed to be negative?

Thank you

**Edit:**

@callculus: This is what I have come up with. Similar problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you define a new variable $x_1=-y_1$?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the max objective function into the table the signs are flipping: $-z=60000y_1-4800y_2-900y_3$ The table is

$$\begin{array}{|m{cm}|m{1cm}|}
\hline y_1   & \color{blue}{y_2} & y_3  & s_1 & s_2  & \textrm{RHS}\\  \hline 
\hline  60000& -4800&-900 & 0 &0&0\\ \hline -50& 6&1&1&0&3  \\ \hline -75&\color{green}{6.75} &1&0&1&\color{orange}{1.8} \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Here $s_1$ and $s_2$ denote the slack variables. The most negative coefficient of the objective function is $-4800$. Thus $y_2$ is the pivot column. And $\min \{\frac{3}{6},\frac{1.8}{6.75}\}=\frac{1.8}{6.75}$. Thus the last row is the pivot row. I think you can go on. The optimal solution is $(y_1^*,y_2^*,y_3^*) = (0.048, 0,5.4)$.

Comment: I encounter the same problem at the 2nd iteration. Can you help me a bit further?
Ghoshhh forgive me. I dont know how to add snapshot or attach a file in comment.

Comment: please refer to my comment for the attached snapshot. 1000 thanks!

Comment: @Kinsley I´ve copied your solution int your quesotion. It looks very good.. If you have no questions anymore please accept the answer.